# Coordinates of specific text fragment in text node

Tags: html, textnode

Is it possible to get bounding rect of specific text fragment inside text node?

Say I have this HTML
    `<p> Word1 word2 word3 word4 </p>`

and I'd like to know bounding rect of word3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not directly, but you could `span` the word and get that span bounding box.

Comment: Thanks, I did this, but I have very long text nodes (part of books), and I need to be able to address any word. When I surround every word with span it took a while to load, so I am looking for faster solution.

Comment: Have you try doing it "on the fly" just for the desired word?. 1.- Add the spans with unique ids (_myspan_number). 2.- read the boxes. 3.- remove spans (you have the ids). Even in a quite long text this could be very fast without too much DOM manipulation.

Comment: Ok, I did some variation of this, so I marked your answer as correct.